# Why can I get BroadcastReceiver in android apps setting only from STOPPED application?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, settings

I declared in AndroidManifest permission and receiver

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS"/>

    <receiver android:name=".UninstallIntentReceiver">
                <intent-filter android:priority="0">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART"/>
                    <data android:scheme="package" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

And here is my java class receiver

```
public class UninstallIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String[] packageNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("android.intent.extra.PACKAGES");

    if(packageNames!=null){
        for(String packageName: packageNames){
            Log.d("User selected: ",packageName);
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on app from this menu [android settings->Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqu3Z.jpg) my class UninstallIntentReceiver has to get notification, but it works only, if some application is stopped, for example, if I open Adobe Acrobat settings and press Force Stop, my application will be able to get notification because this app was stopped

Why can not I get receiver if some app is running ?